# class Double is abstract; cannot be instantiated in scala

Tags: scala, linkedhashmap

```
object demo 
{
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit=
  {
      val temp: LinkedHashMap[String,Object]=new 
      LinkedHashMap[String,Object]()
      temp.put("apple", new Double(1));
      // here i received error since double is abstract class and cannot instantitaed
   }
}
```

Error i received was due to abstract class instance i want to instance a integer how to achieve this

Comment: If you wanted to pass Java's class Double you should change it like so:
`new Double(1)` to `new java.lang.Double(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want a `scala.Double`, read on. If you want a java `Double`, see Duelist's comment

To create a `Double`, you can add the decimal point, as

```
1.0
```

where the compiler will infer it's a `Double`. Or, if you have a value `val a: Int = 1`, you can provide an explicit type as

```
a: Double
```

or convert

```
a.toDouble
```

However, if you want an integer instance (as you said), then just use `1`. The compiler will infer it's an `Int`